¿Es posible pasar el test de Accesibilidad Play Console Flutter android:id/content/s[1]?
Recién creé mi cuenta de play console y me dispuse a subir mi app hecha en flutter, en le apartado de informe previo de lanzamiento , la sección de accesibilidad siempre me marca el error:  Advertencia - Etiqueta del elemento Ruta de elemento android:id/content/s[1]; encerrando toda la pantalla.
Esta es la primera pantalla y se observa es capturada 523 veces en este caso.

Ya he agregado varios Semantics() incluso dentro del runApp(), que se supone engloba toda la app; pero aun así no se soluciona.
Mi pregunta es si existe manera de solucionarlo y pasar el test de google play, según se play console puede rechazar app por tema de accesibilidad además de los 20 testers que piden actualmente.
De no ser posible directamente en flutter, quizás se pueda hacer de manera nativa o en el peor de los casos, luego de compilar el app , usar alguna herramienta de des compilación como APKTOOL alterar el código y volver a compilar.
Nota: He utilizado la app de Accessibility Scanner y si me reconoce todos los elementos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El problema de accesibilidad puede estar relacionado con la organización de los widgets en tu diseño. Asegúrate de que los elementos no estén ocultando o superponiendo otros.
Navegación y Foco: Verifica que la navegación y el enfoque sean lógicos y accesibles.
TalkBack: Activa TalkBack en un dispositivo físico para comprobar cómo se leen los elementos en voz alta.
Android Accessibility Suite: Usa esta suite para detectar problemas adicionales.
Nota: La densidad visual puede afectar la accesibilidad. Por ejemplo, he notado que en diferentes dispositivos físicos, que los elementos pueden aparecer más grandes o más pequeños que en un emulador. Esto puede hacer que un botón o ícono se vea distinto dependiendo del dispositivo, por lo que es crucial probar en varios dispositivos físicos para garantizar que los tamaños de los elementos sean correctos y accesibles.
Saludos,
